# How to add another Eclipse project as a library?

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I want to use this [PhotoView Project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) as Library project in eclipse. Can you please guide me How can I add this project into my eclipse and use it as library for my another project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is step by step instruction for adding a project as Library project into your workspace,

- First of all click on Eclipse's file menu and select "Import" option ( or you can right click on Package Explorer and select "Import" option )
- This will load following dialog

  [image]
- Here you can import project using any of the option either by "Existing Project into Workspace" or by "Existing Android Code into Workspace" ( For your requirement you can choose second import option )
- Click on Next button and give the proper path of your library project, this will import your library project into eclipse.
- Now right click on that project and select "Properties" option, This will load following dialog

  [image]
- Here you can verify if it is library project or not, if not then tick on "Is Library" check box as displayed in the above image.
- Now close this dialog and create new Android Project.
- Again right click on this new Project and you will see same above second image, but here for this project "Is Library" is not check.
- Now click on "Add" button into that dialog box like following image

  [image]
- This will load another dialog box like below

  [image]
- This dialog box lists all the library projects you have.
- Select your library project and click on OK button.

  [image]
- Note that your library project and your Android Project must be at same location otherwise eclipse will not load your library project and will give you error. You can see in following image,

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just import the library as an existing project, then  right-click on the project you want to use the library in, click `Properties`, select the `Android` tab and add the library project to the list here:

[image]

There is information on this in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Answer (score 0):

Select Project Properties and click Android, right side you can see all the Project Build targets....Below that there is text Area and right side of that add button is there, click on add button and select your library project. Finally click on Apply and OK.

Answer (score 0):

First Import your project (which is going to be used as Library project). Then create your new project (In which you are going to use library project). Then right click on the new project -> go to properties > Android > and there add your library project.